# Algorithm for sorting array of objects by a nested value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Im trying to write an algorithm for sorting objects in an array by a value in the objects. This is obviously easy to do, however I am trying to make the function flexible so it will sort by any value I pass in as the first parameter.

***So lets say I have the following data structure:***

```
var data = [
  {
    employee: {
      age: 12,
      paylevel: {
        plevel: '2'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    employee: {
      age: 19,
      paylevel: {
        level: '1'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to be able call the function as seen below and sort for any given value and sort by that specific passed in value.

```
sort('level', data);
```

Or

```
sort('age', data);
```

***Here is my working version:***

```
function sort(prop, data) {
  var key = prop;
  var parts = [];

  function _r(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        _r(data[i]);
      }
    } else if (typeof data === 'object') {
      for (var property in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(property) && parts.indexOf(property) === -1) {
          if (property === key) {
            parts.push(property);
            break;
          } else {
            if (typeof data[property] === 'object') parts.push(property);
            _r(data[property]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  _r(data);

  data.sort((a, d) => {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < parts.length) {
      a = a[parts[i]];
      d = d[parts[i]];
      i++;
    }
    return a - d;
  });

  return data;
}

var res = sort('glevel', data);
```

I am basically using a recursive function to attempt to build the tree structure leading down to the passed in key while adding the parent keys to an array to be used later for sorting.

So if I pass in level, the recursive function (_r) will build a parts array with the following:

```
['employee', 'paylevel', 'level']
```

Then I use that to sort the array by looping into the data structure with a while loop and applying the javascript sort method to the results. This works great with the given data structure. But if I take the current data structure and add another object with a child key/value pair it breaks. So the following data structure will break my code:

```
[
  {
    employee: {
      age: 12,
      paylevel: {
        level: '1'
      },
      grouplevel: {
        glevel: '1'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    employee: {
      age: 19,
      paylevel: {
        level: '3'
      },
      grouplevel: {
        glevel: '2'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

***Because the parts array now looks like this:***

```
['employee', 'paylevel', 'level', 'glevel']
```

Adding the 'glevel' key to the array basically breaks the ability of the while loop to identify the correct item to sort. Is there a way to take a given key and build a tree structure of the parent objects and only include the parent keys:

I hope this wasn't confusing. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, a sort callback is so trivial that I mostly fail to see the point of such a complicated function. `data.sort((a, b) => a.employee.age - b.employee.age)`

Comment: Lol, as I stated early in my opening statement, its easy to do what you just did. I am trying to do this exercise for my own learning experience to become better at solving challenges and improve my understanding of Javascript. This question is more about fun and not practical application. But thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to take a given key and build a tree structure of the parent objects and only include the parent keys

The good thing about programming is that if you can state your problem clearly in English, chances are you can just translate that into a program. Just do what you stated:

```
var parts = [];
function _r(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        // I didn't understand why you looped through all elements
        // I think i'll just visit the first element
        // In fact it might be better to take this call out of the function
        return _r(data[0]);
    } else {
        for(var property in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                // assume that _r will return you a boolean
                // that tells you whether or not
                // key was found in this property
                var didIFindAKey = _r(data.property);
                // if yes, then add this property to parts
                if (didIFindAKey) {
                    // Note that we need to PRE-pend the property
                    // to the beginning of parts, due to the nature
                    // of the recursion
                    parts.unshift(property);
                    // make the assumption above come true:
                    //     return true since you have found the key
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        // make the assumption above come true:
        //     return false since no property found the key
        return false;
    }
}
```

I haven't tried it, so good chance it might contain minor errors. Hopefully you get the idea and can make it work. Feel free to ask questions in the comments, and please definitely point out any errors so that i can correct my answer.

Comment: Also note that instead of PRE-pending into the parts array, you can alternatively append to the end of the array, and then just reverse the array once the recursion is finally complete. Another alternative is to let the array be reversed, and just reverse the while loop traversal.